# shmget size limit issue

Tags: c++, shared-memory

I have this snippet of code:

```
if ((shmid = shmget(key, 512, IPC_CREAT | 0666)) < 0)
{   
    perror("shmget");
    exit(1);
}
```

Whenever I set the number any higher than 2048, I get, an error that says:

```
shmget: Invalid argument
```

However when I run `cat /proc/sys/kernel/shmall`, I get `4294967296`.

Does anybody know why this is happening? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about this: `EINVAL: ... a segment with given key existed, but size is greater than the size of that segment.`

Comment: I hard code it as 512, and I am deallocating it so I don't think that's what's happening.

Comment: Do you know a way to programmatically get SHMALL in C++ so I can just replace my hardcoded value with that? I get this error when I try to use it:
parse.cpp:135: error: ‘SHMALL’ was not declared in this scope I have include <sys/ipc.h> and <sys/shm.h>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comment from Jerry is correct, even if cryptic if you haven't played with this stuff: "What about this: `EINVAL: ... a segment with given key existed, but size is greater than the size of that segment.`"

He meant that the segment is already there - these segment are persistent - and it has size 2048.

You can see it among the other ones with:

```
$ ipcs -m
```

and you can remove your segment (beware: remove your one only) with:

```
$ ipcrm -M <key>
```

After that you should be able to create it larger.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, the ipcrm -M command fixed it right up, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

[man 5 proc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) refers to three variables related to `shmget(2)`:

> - `/proc/sys/kernel/shmall`
>     This file contains the system-wide limit on the total number of pages of System V shared memory.
> - `/proc/sys/kernel/shmmax`
>     This file can be used to query and set the run-time limit on the maximum (System V IPC) shared memory segment size that can be created.  Shared memory segments up to 1GB are now supported in the kernel.  This value defaults to SHMMAX.
> - `/proc/sys/kernel/shmmni`
>     (available in Linux 2.4 and onward) This file specifies the system-wide maximum number of System V shared memory segments that can be created.

Please check you violated none of them.  Note that `shmmax` and `SHMMAX` are in bytes and `shmall` and `SHMALL` are in the number of pages (the page size is usually 4 KB but you should use `sysconf(PAGESIZE)`.)  I personally felt your `shmall` is too large (2**32 pages == 16 TB) but not sure if it is harmful or not.

As for the definition of `SHMALL`, I got this result on my Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64 system:

```
$ ack SHMMAX /usr/include
/usr/include/linux/shm.h
9: * SHMMAX, SHMMNI and SHMALL are upper limits are defaults which can
13:#define SHMMAX 0x2000000              /* max shared seg size (bytes) */
16:#define SHMALL (SHMMAX/getpagesize()*(SHMMNI/16))

/usr/include/linux/sysctl.h
113:    KERN_SHMMAX=34,         /* long: Maximum shared memory segment */
```